# Unable to disble the sibling from table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to disable the input type from adjacent columns when a checkbox is checked for that row. I have tried as below but unable to disable. Please have a look and suggest how to disable.

```js
$("input:checkbox[class=associationcheckbox]").each(function() {
  var index;
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.associationCheckbox1').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.associationCheckbox1').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Balu</td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Balu" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox1" type="number" name="Balu" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Balu</td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Balu" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox1" type="number" name="Balu" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Balu</td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Balu" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox1" type="number" name="Balu" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're including jQuery twice - is that just an error in your snippet?

Comment: your condition is same disable to false can you clarify what you wanted? both if and else is putting `.prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: Hi Guradio, Sorry. A small typo here.When I check checkbox it should be disabled else it is in enabled state.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/koqasiqiza/3/edit?html,js,output - Original One

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors are a little all over the place. The cases of the classes need to match, you don't need the `each()` and you're trying to select the `td` by the class of the `input`, which will never work. You also set `disabled` to `false` in both sides of the `if` condition, but I assume that's just a typo.

To achieve what you need you can just add a single click handler to the checkbox by class, and find it's related textbox and set it as disabled/enabled based on the `checked` property. Try this:

```js
$(".associationCheckbox").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.associationCheckbox1').prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Balu</td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Balu" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox1" type="number" name="Balu" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Balu</td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Balu" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox1" type="number" name="Balu" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Balu</td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Balu" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="associationCheckbox1" type="number" name="Balu" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I would also suggest you change the class of the textbox as `associationCheckbox1` is a little confusing.

Comment: Hi Rory. It works perfectly. Thank you. I will change the class names.